# How to add values/ labels over each marker in lineplot in Python Seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, line-plot

I have a dataframe consists of the range of time, stock and the counts of text as the columns . The dataframe looks like this

```
              Time Stock  Text
0   00:00 - 01:00  BBNI   371
1   00:00 - 01:00  BBRI   675
2   00:00 - 01:00  BBTN   136
3   00:00 - 01:00  BMRI   860
4   01:00 - 02:00  BBNI   936
5   01:00 - 02:00  BBRI  1325
6   01:00 - 02:00  BBTN   316
7   01:00 - 02:00  BMRI  1630
```

I want to draw a lineplot with the codes below :

```
df=tweetdatacom.groupby(["Time","Stock"])[["Text"]].count().reset_index()
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
line=sn.lineplot(x="Time", y="Text",hue="Stock",palette=["green","orange","red","blue"],marker="o",data=df)
plt.xticks(size=5,rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right',fontweight='light',fontsize='large')
plt.xlabel('Time Interval',size=12)
plt.ylabel('Total Tweets',size=12)
```

This is the result that I get with the codes :
[image]

Now, I want to put the value for each marker on the plot, how can I do that?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through the number of data with `ax.text`. I'm creating this only with the data presented to me, so I'm omitting some of your processing.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
 Time Stock Text
0 "00:00 - 01:00"  BBNI 371
1 "00:00 - 01:00"  BBRI 675
2 "00:00 - 01:00"  BBTN 136
3 "00:00 - 01:00"  BMRI 860
4 "01:00 - 02:00"  BBNI 936
5 "01:00 - 02:00"  BBRI 1325
6 "01:00 - 02:00"  BBTN 316
7 "01:00 - 02:00"  BMRI 1630
'''

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\s+')
import seaborn as sn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# df=tweetdatacom.groupby(["Time","Stock"])[["Text"]].count().reset_index()

plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))

palette = ["green","orange","red","blue"]
line=sn.lineplot(x="Time", y="Text",hue="Stock",palette=palette, marker="o", data=df)

plt.xticks(size=5,rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right',fontweight='light',fontsize='large')
plt.xlabel('Time Interval',size=12)
plt.ylabel('Total Tweets',size=12)

for item, color in zip(df.groupby('Stock'),palette):
    for x,y,m in item[1][['Time','Text','Text']].values:
#         print(x,y,m)
        plt.text(x,y,m,color=color)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It's working! I've tried to find any relevant literature regarding this label plotting but can't find any..

Comment: This worked really well, except the label colors were switched for me